# Joomla | New developer | Write option in database

Tags: wordpress, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am a new Joomla Developer and I try to create a module for the Joomla and I like to write some options in the Database for that module.

In WordPress I have a function "add_option()" that allowing me to write some options to the Global WordPress Options table.

In Joomla is there anything similar? Is there a way to write some options in database without creating a new table ?

In case there is no available that option, Is there any article/tutorial to help me on Joomla Table creation and data adding into that table ?

Comment: for what purpose you want to add extra option in module ?..you can use params for extra option !

Comment: What do you mean by options what is a option in Wordpress?

Comment: see the right side of the module in back end..you can see like Basic option & Advance option

Comment: By the module installation, I like to get a random message and then writed into the database for the specific web site. Then, the module, at the frontEnd I like to display that message. But that message must be the same for that site until the plugin will be removed.

Comment: An option in WordPress is something like global configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go with this link it really helps you to create new module in joomla..

```
http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_simple_module
```

Actually what you want exact can u please explain here what you going to do in Joomla? Because by using joomla we can create components,modules,plugins. Each elements was used for different purpose.

Need  better clarification form you.. :)

Comment: As I describe in my message I try to create a module.

Comment: Then you have to follow the above link.. That should guide you to create module in joomla.